# Javascript - Partial Download of FLV Starting from X Seconds

Tags: javascript, flv

I want to partially download a FLV file starting from X seconds. How do you calculate the byte offset of the X in the file ?

I was going through the the [FLV format](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/flv/pdfs/video_file_format_spec_v10.pdf) but I can't figure out how to achieve this.

Thanks.

Comment: its not like an audio tape you can just trim, there are sections and headers you need. some mpeg formats can be chopped, and many players will be able to parse broken files, but results will vary.

Comment: i am interested in this. you tube seems to do this. Click half way through a loading video and it appears to buffer from that point.

Comment: youtube is doing more than just a range header, those streams are build on-demand by a backend video server.